# Problemas ao mapear banco de dados Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou tendo problemas em criar uma solução para essa regra de negócios.

Tenho atualmente 1 Cliente, 1 Correspondente e 1 Loja.
Ambos utilizam a mesma tabela de Endereço.
Como as tabelas `cliente`, `correspondente` e `loja` não podem ter o Id auto gerável, resolvi usar `GUID` para não ocorrer erro de duplicidade na tabela `Endereco`.
Nesse caso a tabela `Endereco` deve ficar assim:

```
EnderecoId - ReferenceId          - Logradouro
1          - GuidDoCorrespondente - Rua tal tal tal
2          - GuidDaLoja           - Rua tal tal tal
3          - GuidCliente          - Rua tal tal tal
```

Porém estou tendo problemas para mapear as entidades. Segue o modelo que estou tentando fazer:

```
        EnderecoMap() 
        {

        HasKey(x => x.EnderecoId);

        Property(x => x.Logradouro)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(60);

        Property(x => x.Numero)
            .IsRequired();

        HasRequired(x => x.Correspondente)
            .WithMany(x => x.Enderecos)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReferenceId);

        HasRequired(x => x.Cliente)
            .WithMany(x => x.Enderecos)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReferenceId);

        HasRequired(x => x.Loja)
            .WithMany(x => x.Enderecos)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReferenceId);
        }
```

Sempre recebo os seguintes erros:

Se eu adicionar um cliente e referenciar assim:

```
public void AdicionandoLivro()
    {
        var cliente = new Cliente("Default",   
                  "default@outlook.com");
        cliente.AddEndereco(new Endereco(cliente.ClienteId, "Rua"));


        _clienteRepository.Add(cliente);
        _uow.Commit();
    }
```

Recebo esse erro:

```
 {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Endereco_dbo.Correspondente_ReferenceId\". The conflict occurred in database \"LivrariaEF\", table \"dbo.Correspondente\", column 'CorrespondenteId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`
```

Quando adiciono um `Correspondente` com o código semelhante me gera o erro invertido:

```
{"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Endereco_dbo.Cliente_ReferenceId\". The conflict occurred in database \"LivrariaEF\", table \"dbo.Cliente\", column 'ClienteId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

Se alguém poder me ajudar agradeceria muito!

---

Fiz as modificações como você sugeriu e meu mapeamento ficou assim:

```
ClienteMap()
HasMany(x => x.EnderecosCliente)
            .WithOptional(x => x.Cliente)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ClienteId);

CorrespondenteMap()
HasMany(x => x.EnderecosCorrespondente)
            .WithOptional(x => x.Correspondente)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CorrespondenteId);
```

- Não precisa colocar o dbset de EnderecosCorrespondente e EnderecosCliente?

Quando vou adicionar no Banco, ele não cria nada na tabela de Endereço. Apenás na tabela Correspondente ou Cliente. Estou usando esse código para salvar no banco:

```
var correspondente = new Correspondente()
        {
            CorrespondenteId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Nome = "Walmart",
            EnderecosCorrespondente = new List<EnderecoCorrespondente>()
            {
                new EnderecoCorrespondente() { Logradouro = "Rua 1",  Numero = "1" },
                new EnderecoCorrespondente() { Logradouro = "Rua 2", Numero = "2" }
            }
        };

        _correspondenteRepository.Add(correspondente);
        _uow.Commit();
```

Será que estou fazendo map correto da relação?

Comment: Esse erro ocorre quando você faz o mapeamento e cria a migração ou quando vai inserir ? Sua pergunta me deixou confuso sobre isso. Se caso for na inserção, você esta inserindo o cliente antes do endereço?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com mais explicações. VLW!

Comment: "Não precisa colocar o dbset de EnderecosCorrespondente e EnderecosCliente?", precisa. Aliás, precisa também mais um: `public DbSet<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }`

Comment: Realmente só estava faltando o dbSet de EnderecosCorrespondente e EnderecosCliente. Obrigado mais uma vez pela força Cigano. Abraços!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode fazer isto:

```
    HasRequired(x => x.Correspondente)
        .WithMany(x => x.Enderecos)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReferenceId);

    HasRequired(x => x.Cliente)
        .WithMany(x => x.Enderecos)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReferenceId);

    HasRequired(x => x.Loja)
        .WithMany(x => x.Enderecos)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReferenceId);
```

Isso exige que `Endereco` tenha um `Correspondente` **e** uma `Loja` **e** um `Cliente`, o que não é o que você quer.

O correto é você fazer o seguinte:

```
public class Endereco
{
    [Key]
    public Guid EnderecoId { get; set; }
    public int? CorrespondenteId { get; set; }
    public int? LojaId { get; set; }
    public int? ClienteId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual Correspondente Correspondente { get; set; }
    public virtual Loja Loja { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

Agora, se a ideia é ter uma só chave estrangeira, você terá que fazer `Correspondente`, `Loja` e `Cliente` herdarem do mesmo ancestral:

```
public class Reference
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ReferenceId { get; set; }

    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente: Reference
{
    ...
}

public class Correspondente: Reference
{
    ...
}

public class Loja: Reference
{
    ...
}
```

E:

```
public class Endereco
{
    [Key]
    public Guid EnderecoId { get; set; }
    public Guid ReferenceId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual Reference Reference { get; set; }
}
```

O problema é que as três entidades ficarão numa tabela chamada `References`, com um campo a mais chamado `Discriminator`.

Esta é uma limitação do SQL Server (e de bancos de dados relacionais, em geral): não do Entity Framework. Para que haja a devida integridade referencial (com a conferência de chaves), `Endereco` precisa referenciar uma tabela só. Chaves estrangeiras não podem ser destinadas a três tabelas diferentes.

---

Conforme solicitado por comentário, outra coisa que você pode fazer é derivar `Endereco` em mais três entidades diferentes:

```
public class Endereco
{
    [Key]
    public Guid EnderecoId { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class EnderecoCorrespondente : Endereco
{
    public int? CorrespondenteId { get; set; }

    ...
    public virtual Correspondente Correspondente { get; set; }
}

public class EnderecoLoja : Endereco
{
    public int? LojaId { get; set; }

    ...
    public virtual Loja Loja { get; set; }
}

public class EnderecoCliente : Endereco
{
    public int? ClienteId { get; set; }

    ...
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

E a relação inversa:

```
public class Cliente
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<EnderecoCliente> EnderecosCliente { get; set; }
}

public class Correspondente
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<EnderecoCorrespondente> EnderecosCorrespondente { get; set; }
}

public class Loja
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<EnderecoLoja> EnderecosLoja { get; set; }
}
```

Isso torna a tabela de endereços unificada. Dois pontos aqui:

1. `Endereco` não pode ser `abstract` e precisa ter o próprio `DbSet`:

   ```
   public DbSet<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
   ```
2. Mesmo com isso, endereços não têm como ser reaproveitados. Para reaprovietá-los, seria necessário algum esquema associativo.

Comment: Opa, Cigano blz? Vlw pela resposta cara.
Então por essa limitação, vc acha que seria mais viável eu utilizar uma chave composta?
Ai na tabela endereço ficaria o 
`Tipo - Id - Logradouro
Loja - 1 - Rua tal tal tal
Cliente - 1 - Rua tal tal tal`

Ou seria melhor separar essas entidades?
Por ex: Correspondente - EnderecoCorrespondente
             Loja - EnderecoLoja

Abraço!

Comment: Tudo joia, e você? Não acho chave composta uma boa para este caso. Separar como `EnderecoCorrespondente`, `EnderecoLoja` e `EnderecoCliente` pode ser uma boa! Gostaria que eu ampliasse a resposta?

Comment: Não não, sem problemas Cigano. Era só para saber se não seria uma má prática.
É q já havia tido essa ideia de separar os enderecos por entidades, mas ela não foi bem recebida na equipe. Agora posso ter argumentos para poder usar assim.
Obrigado pela ajuda cara =). Abraços!

Comment: Se a resposta te atendeu, [dê uma passada pelo Tour para entender como o site funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Um abraço!

Comment: Opa Cigano tudo bem? Vou dar uma testada nessa forma de fazer. Como não poderia ficar tudo na mesma tabela pesquisei e encontrei sobre o TPT(Table per Type). Será que ela me ajudaria a ter uma tabela Endereco com o Discriminator falando para qual tabela ele está olhando? weblogs.asp.net/manavi/… Estou tentando implementar essa forma que você indicou por aqui e por tutoriais mas está muito difícil pra mim compreender e implementar. Pode dar uma força? Abraços!

Comment: @allan.egidio Veja minha edição. Outro abraço!

Comment: Outra coisa: não sei se te interessa, mas [eu tenho um curso](http://www.codingcraft.com.br/2016/08/10/coding-craft-asp-net-mvc-e-asp-net-web-api-modulo-1-turma-de-10-de-setembro-de-2016/). Se tiver interesse, [só me contatar pelo Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/cigano.m.mendez).

Comment: Dei uma atualizada na pergunta, tem como dar uma olhada?
Acabei de olhar seu curso e achei bem legal, possivelmente entrarei em contato com você dps.

Comment: Opa Cigano, blz? Sou eu de novo rsrs. Cara atualizei a pergunta com uma dúvida. Tem como dar uma olhada? Abraços!

Comment: @allan.egidio Suave, e você? Isso já é outra pergunta. Abra outra pergunta, por favor. Outro abraço!

Comment: De boa cara, Tranquilo vou criar aqui.