# Relacionamento EF vindo de migração Foxpro, com chave composta

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou migrando um sistema em VisualFox legado em .Net onde as tabelas foram feitas tudo sem relacionamento, em ADO, sem *foreign key* nos relacionamentos.
Apenas comparando uma string do nome "Tipo" para diferenciar se o registro em uma Tabela, por ex: Endereço pertence a Correspondente, Loja ou Cliente.

O sistema é muito grande e existem diversos relacionamentos semelhantes a esse por exemplo: Loja e Correspondente possuem uma tabela Contato também relacionando o ID e diferenciando pelo Tipo(string).

Está muito difícil espelhar essa regra no EF (isso se possível, pois sou iniciante e ainda estou aprendendo). A tabela fica assim:

```
EnderecoId - ReferenceId          - Tipo                 - Logradouro
1          - 1                    - Loja                 - Rua tal tal tal
2          - 1                    - Correspondente       - Rua tal tal tal
3          - 1                    - Correspondente       - Rua tal tal tal
4          - 1                    - Cliente              - Rua tal tal tal
```

É possível fazer essas regra utilizando uma string Tipo como forma de diferenciar os endereços? Se não é possível, seria certo usar Chave Composta nesse caso?

Comment: O que quer dizer a última frase?

Comment: É que ele editou a pergunta anterior, mas essa é uma dúvida completamente diferente.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201008/problemas-ao-mapear-banco-de-dados-entity-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Entity Framework nativamente não tem essa capacidade de intuir o tipo da tabela relacionada automaticamente, por uso de uma coluna, por exemplo.

No seu lugar, eu faria um tabalho no SQL para melhorar essa tabela. [Lembrando a abordagem 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/201415/2999), adicionaria 3 colunas novas na sua tabela:

```
ALTER TABLE Enderecos
ADD LojaId int null,
    ClienteId int null,
    CorrespondenteId int null;
```

Faria 3 `UPDATE`s para popular essas colunas:

```
UPDATE Enderecos
SET LojaId = ReferenceId
WHERE Tipo = 'Loja' ;

UPDATE Enderecos
SET ClienteId = ReferenceId
WHERE Tipo = 'Cliente' ;

UPDATE Enderecos
SET CorrespondenteId = ReferenceId
WHERE Tipo = 'Correspondente' ;
```

Teremos, portanto:

```
EnderecoId + ReferenceId  + Tipo            + Logradouro      + LojaId + ClienteId + CorrespondenteId
1          | 1            | Loja            | Rua tal tal tal | 1      | null      | null
2          | 1            | Correspondente  | Rua tal tal tal | null   | 1         | null
3          | 1            | Correspondente  | Rua tal tal tal | null   | 1         | null
4          | 1            | Cliente         | Rua tal tal tal | null   | null      | 1
```

Apenas com isso o Entity Framework é capaz de entender a relação pela abordagem 1 (usando herança).

Comment: Opa, vlw pela resposta Cigano!
Então justamente por isso que a abordagem 1, não foi aceita pelo pessoal aqui por LojaId, ClienteId e CorrespondenteId ser inserido null.  Pensei que usando o Tipo e ReferenceID, eu eliminaria o problema das chaves serem null. Mas parece que não é possível também né? 
Também não posso usar aquela abordagem de ter Cliente, ClienteEndereco, Correspondente, CorrespondenteEndereco pq falaram que iria ter muitas tabelas.
Minha impressão é que estão tentando criar algo que não existe.
Ta complicado...

Comment: Acho que falta conhecimento da equipe. Herança, como exposto na abordagem 1, cria uma tabela só, `Endereco` com uma coluna `Discriminator` que especifica o tipo de cada entidade de endereço. É mais ou menos o que você tem hoje com a coluna `Tipo`, só que no formato que o *framework* trabalha.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Quando fiz essa abordagem com o Discriminator, também fiquei com  LojaId, ClienteId ou CorrespondenteId vindo null. Vendo a tabela que você criou agora pouco, a minha só ficou sem o ReferenceId e Tipo. Apenas informações do endereço, Discriminator e as chaves que podem ser null. Perfeitamente normal né?

Comment: Sim. Os valores de `Discriminator` serão `EnderecoCorrespondente`, `EnderecoLoja` e `EnderecoCliente`. Um pouco diferente, mas nada que uma migração de dados não resolva.

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda novamente Cigano. Um abraço!